# В чем разница между ForMember() и ForPath() методов AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода, automapper, expressions

Читая про `ReversMap()` у AutoMapper, не могу понять разницу между методами `ForMember` и `ForPath`. Тот функционал, который выполняет `ForPath` на данной [странице](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening) я обычно делаю с помощью `ForMember`.

Вот пример, где я конфигурирую двухсторонний маппинг и все работает правильно:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
public class CustomerDto
{
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerDto>()
           .ForMember(dist => dist.CustomerName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => $"{src.Surname} {src.Name}"))
            .ReverseMap()
            .ForMember(dist => dist.Surname, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CustomerName.Split(' ')[0]))
            .ForMember(dist => dist.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CustomerName.Split(' ')[1]));
    });

    // код с маппингом Customer -> CustomerDto            
    //... 
    //

    // код с маппингом CustomerDto -> Customer
    var customerDto = new CustomerDto
    {
        CustomerName = "Shakhabov Adam",
        Age = 31
    };
    var newCustomer = Mapper.Map<CustomerDto, Customer>(customerDto);
}
```

---

### Вопрос

Методы `ForMember` и `ForPath` в чем то дублируют функционал? Или что нельзя сделать с `ForMember`, но можно с `ForPath`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это легко выяснить заглянув [в исходники](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/3f6d0bc59a8f3a46dd6785881429f9d8bfa172a9/src/AutoMapper/Configuration/MappingExpression.cs).

`ForMember` не выполняет никаких проверок и обрабатывает любое выражение c `IMemberConfigurationExpression`.

```
    public IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> ForMember<TMember>(Expression<Func<TDestination, TMember>> destinationMember,
                                                               Action<IMemberConfigurationExpression<TSource, TDestination, TMember>> memberOptions)
    {
        var memberInfo = ReflectionHelper.FindProperty(destinationMember);
        return ForDestinationMember(memberInfo, memberOptions);
    }
```

`ForPath` же работает только с [`IPathConfigurationExpression`](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/c51b0e02fed38cd93b70dfe682636cd8f32ea326/src/AutoMapper/IPathConfigurationExpression.cs) и для прочих членов бросает исключение.

```
public IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> ForPath<TMember>(Expression<Func<TDestination, TMember>> destinationMember,
        Action<IPathConfigurationExpression<TSource, TDestination>> memberOptions)
    {
        if(!destinationMember.IsMemberPath())
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(destinationMember), "Only member accesses are allowed.");
        }
        ...
```

Если тебе нужен функционал, описываемый интерфейсом `IPathConfigurationExpression`, используй `ForPath`, в противном случае - `ForMember`

Пример использования метода `Ignore()` на той же странице по твоей ссылке:

```
cfg.CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>()
    .ForMember(d => d.CustomerName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Customer.Name))
    .ReverseMap()
    .ForPath(s => s.Customer.Name, opt => opt.Ignore());
```